# jQuery get correct acces to plugin object in each function

Tags: jquery, object, jquery-plugins, chaining

Is it possible to get access to jQuery's plugin object in `each`-function?

```
var pluginName = 'pluginName',
    Plugin = function(elem){
        elem.add = function () {
            console.log('foo');
            return this;
        };
    };

$.fn[pluginName] = function () {

    // this works
    new Plugin(this);
    return this;

    // this doesn't!
    // return this.each(function(){
    //     new Plugin($(this));
    // });
};

var plugin = $('.foo').pluginName();
plugin.add();
```

Comment: Notice you are assigning the `add` function in the anonymous function to a different jQuery object than the one that is returned. I may ask what are you trying to pull off?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "this does not work"? What happens and what do you expect to happen? Inside a jQuery method, `this` refers to the jQuery object, so `this.each(...)` should work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context when you go inside of a `.each()` is not the same context as outside.  You can maintain the context with a variable like this:

```
var _this = this;
return this.each(function(){
     new Plugin($(_this));
});
```

Comment: Yeah, problem is that this doesn't iterate over the elements, like `each` does it normally...

Answer (score 0):

Mash got it almost right, but the correct code would be,

```
var _this = this;
return _this.each(function(){
     console.log($(this));
     new Plugin($(this));
});
```

Though I could not get the point, what this add supposed to do?

Comment: Your code accomplishes no change, mine is actually correct.  You are setting `_this` to equal `this`, then iterating over the elements of `_this`, (equivalent to `this`) at that time, then using `this` inside the function, which references the object being iterated, NOT the object associated with the plugin.